# Can't create Dynamic UI element in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx, uielement

I want to generate JSX for UI dynamically in real time . I declare global setState

```
 this.state = {
      updatedNumOfLayer: 1
     }
```

and create one function handleChange

```
   handleChange = (event) => {

      this.setState({
  updatedNumOfLayer: event.target.value
})
```

My UI element is generating as per the value of 'this.state.updatedNumOfLayer'. Now I want to generate UI element in real time(When user is passing the value in textfield )

```
   {[...Array((this.state.updatedNumOfLayer))].map((value, index) => {
    console.log("updatedNumOfLayer "+ this.state.updatedNumOfLayer)
          return(
             <TextField
               id="outlined-read-only-input"
                label=""
                value={"Layer " + (index + 1)}                     
                margin="dense" style={{ height: 38 }}
                InputProps={{
                readOnly: true,
                disableUnderline: true,
                style: { fontSize: 12, padding: 10 }
                 }}
                              variant="standard"
                              size="small"
                            />
                           )
                          })}
```

But UI is not rendering.
does anyone know how to I accomplimsh or any guidance, reference appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any console errors in your browser? Maybe try adding key=index.toString() to your TextField

Comment: It looks like you're not updating your state from your textfield. Try adding ```onChange={handleChange}``` to your TextField.